# What URLs do Google Play Services require access to?

Tags: android, google-play-services

My app has to receive push-notifications and right now am getting `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` after `GoogleCloudMessaging.register()` call.

My client has a strict firewall in his office and he doesn't have access to Google Play Services. I need to provide him a list of all URL's that Google Play services needs access to, so he can add it to white list.

So far there's only one url in my list: googleapis.com

I didn't find any information on this subject, so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all GCM-communication is HTTPS, so I think the question should actually be more like "What domains/IP-addresses does GCM require access to?".

Comment: Never mind, what I said above seems incorrect, see my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html), it seems this is your answer:

> **Note:** If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your Android devices to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in [Google's ASN of 15169](http://bgp.he.net/AS15169#_prefixes).

Update with FCM

[Official doc for firewall handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall)

Comment: Doing so would authorize every IPs owned by Google. Including all their derivatives. Why not using \*/\* while you are at it ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the interception of the requests of google services API, we can see the used hostname is :  **1e100.net**

[image]

And is described on google support :  In October 2009, we started using a single domain name to identify our servers across all Google products, rather than use different product domains such as youtube.com, blogger.com, and google.com.