# How to allow google play service(FCM push notification) to run in restricted network

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am working on an in-house application that will run on a restricted network. Clients will allow traffic only on those links and ports which the application is using. I have listed out all the external URLs. But I am concerned about FCM. My App receives FCM push notifications form server hence have FCM integrated.
I am quite sure that it will not work unless it's allowed via the firewall . So my question is what port numbers or URLs should I allow I order to receive push notifications?

I have done some digging and came across [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947853/what-urls-do-google-play-services-require-access-to) which have an accepted answer but its almost 6 years old. Also, it's asking almost every IP address Google Uses. I can not allow that many Ip address.
So pls help me out here.

Comment: Please check this documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall

Comment: Thanks you very much @kelvin .. I am looking into it .